# Can't access Ubuntu after I installed windows

Tags: 12.04, dual-boot, windows-7

[image]

So What I did to dual boot was split a partion from my Ubuntu section. And then I installed windows onto the one that was empty. And now I can't access Ubuntu. When I startup there is no option on to enter Ubuntu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That happened, because Windows has replaced [GRUB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GRUB) at its proprietary bootloader and has changed [MBR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_boot_record) record.

Now you should repair your GRUB.

You can find instruction [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair).