# Tried to install windows 10 on the same partition as ubuntu

Tags: boot, boot-partition

I tried to install Windows 10 on the same partition on my ssd which was used for ubuntu OS. Now after the completion of installation of Windows 10. The system is just keep restarting but neither of the Windows nor Ubuntu is booting. I am confused what to do. Has anyone gone through this? Please give your opinion to resolve this.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can't access Ubuntu after I installed windows](https://askubuntu.com/questions/264117/cant-access-ubuntu-after-i-installed-windows)

Comment: Please [edit your question](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1479897/edit) to include your desired goal: Do you want an all-Windows system? Or and all-Ubuntu system? Or a dual-boot system? Or something else?

Answer (score 0):

it's look like your MBR or boot loader is overwritten, you need to repair your boot load.
please boot your system by using Ubuntu bootable usb and then boot in live mode.
once done, you need to open terminal and run below command
sudo boot-repair
then select Recommended Repair
please follow the steps and this will repair your boot.

if you didn't find the boot-repair command then please connect your system with internet and run below command

sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair && sudo apt update
sudo apt install -y boot-repair && boot-repair

hope you will be able to see both entries for ubuntu and windows. if you face any issue then please let me know.